# Javascript single var pattern. Am I overloading it?

Tags: javascript, variables

I've read in Stoyan Stefanov book about single var pattern. Also it's good by JSLint.

But I've noticed in my code that I maybe overload this pattern. It occurs that whole my .js file, whole script is just one big var.

For example:

```
$(function(){ 

var
    some_var1   = 'some_value',
    some_var2   = { /* some other value */},

    // more and more vars 

    tiny_fun    = function(){ /* some tiny helper function */ },
    tiny_fun2   = function(){ /* another tiny helper function */},

    // more tiny functions

    Constructor1    = function(){ /* Some Constructor */ },
    Constructor2    = function(){ /* Another Constructor */ },

    script_body     = (function(){

        // main script - 'script body'

        var c1 = new Constructor1();
        c1.some_method();

        // and other client code            
    })(); //: script_body
});
```

Is it bad? maybe I've misunderstood this single-var pattern and should use it only for variables -  to prevent using globals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only grouping private access elements there is no problem at all. Remember that you can't declare public access elements using `var` (global scope is an exception).